# The system can't perform the operation now. Try again later

Tags: google-scholar

The problem statement "The system can't perform the operation now. Try again later." in Google Scholar can be resolved using the following steps.

1. Click on the "View all" that is placed after the "public access" tab at the right side section of the computer screen.
2. "Mandates" and "Review" tab will open. now click on the "Review" tab
3. "Uplaod PDF" and "make a correction" tab will open.
4. Click on "make a correction" tab and select an appropriate option. I prefer to select "This article was not funded by any of these agencies"
5. Click "Done" and hope now the problem is resolved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about programming.

Comment: What if they are funded by one of these agencies? That solution might make your message disappear, but not solving the issue of not being able to upload the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to create a folder in my Google Drive called "Public research articles" and upload the file directly there. Then when I returned to the upload page and retried the upload, it worked correctly.

Without knowing better I'd assume the reason this worked is that all it had to do was create a link to the already present article in Drive.